# How to format List<List<int>> as a table in JSON file?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I use Newtonsoft.Json library for serializing and deserializing .NET objects. 
One of the things I am serializing are tables (represented as `List<List<int>>`).
What I need is to format them in the serialized file like a table, not like a bunch of columns as they are formatted now. Is there any way to achieve this?

Now, I have the following formatting in the json-file:

```
"Table": [
          [
            1024,
            1024,
            1024,
            1024    
          ],
          [
            1024,
            1024,
            1024,
            1024
          ],
          [
            1024,
            1024,
            1024,      
            1024           
          ]
         ]
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
"Table": [
          [1024, 1024, 1024, 1024],
          [1024, 1024, 1024, 1024],
          [1024, 1024, 1024, 1024]                           
         ]
```

Comment: Can you add exaples of current and desireble formats?

Comment: Do you just want to turn the List<List<int>> to JSON?

Comment: List<List<int>> can represent a table very roughly )

Comment: er, you already have what you require. Your expected and actual JSOn representations are the same

Comment: Perhaps your JSON should have no spurious whitespace and you should have a JSON visualiser.

Comment: prasant: I know, that I have a correct representation. I am talking about desired formatting.

Comment: Is this a trick question? The example and desired output are the same, and it took less than 10 seconds in google to find http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/, which then led me straight to http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/ReducingSerializedJSONSize.html

Comment: No tricks at all. It is just all about formatting.

Answer (score 2):

I you want a more compact format there are already some comments below your question about that.
If you want more readability you could use a list of mapping of columnName to columnValue by `List<Map<string /*columndName*/, int>>`