# convert array object to Json as one line in Json (Serialization of array) ASP.NET core3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I'M building Api that need to return json array as response like this :

```json
"tagList": ["dragons", "training"],
```

But I got ((each element in separate line )):

```json
"tagList": [
        "dragons",
        "training"
    ],
```

I was using `System.Text.Json.Serialization;`
I tried to change it to `Json.net` by `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj)` but I got the same result .
could anyone help me ,please ?

Comment: With Json.NET you can, check the accepted answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53223517/creating-json-without-array-indentation

Comment: The two snippets are *identical*. Whitespace isn't significant in JSON. Why do you want the output in a single line? It matters. Are you trying to return streaming JSON aka JSON per line aka newline-delimited JSON perhaps?

Comment: Are you asking how to format a JSON array on a single line **while the containing JSON is formatted on multiple lines** for cosmetic reasons?  If so, this is not possible with System.Text.Json, see [In System.Text.Json is it possible to specify custom indentation rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63376873/3744182).  With Json.NET it is possible, see the previously linked [Creating JSON without array indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53223517/3744182) as well as [Newtonsoft inline formatting for subelement while serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30831895/3744182).

Answer (score 1):

since you are using System.Text.Json.Serialization , try this

```
 JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
  options.WriteIndented = false //not using indent, white space, new line, etc.
    
    string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj, options);
```